# Is baking with wheat starch similar to using other gluten free starches?

Tags: baking, gluten-free

I came across [this article about wheat starch](https://gluten.guide/post/wheat-starch/) being gluten free the other day and it was the first time I'd heard that. It would be nice to experience the texture of wheat bread again.

Has anyone tried baking with wheat starch? Was the texture at all similar to wheat flour with the gluten removed or is it just like any other starch?

Comment: much of the texture of wheat bread comes from the gluten, so bread made with wheat starch and no gluten will likely have a texture more similar to bread made with other starches.

Comment: With the new edits I'm voting to reopen as it seems like a legitimate question (unless there is a duplicate among the many gluten-free baking questions).